# Transfer content of current imageview to another one

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview

I have an ImageView On my current Activity that it fills with a thumbnail picture. I want to enlarge (zoom) this picture when user click on it (in new activity). How i can transfer current Imageview to this new ImageView?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transfer the content to the activity and then load it to your new `ImageView`.

```
Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream );
byte[] bytes = stream .toByteArray();                               
Intent i = new Intent(this, newActivity.class);
i.putExtra("BMP",bytes);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the new activity just decode the bitmap;

```
byte[] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("BMP");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
newImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: what's stream object in first section?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, check my update. stream is a ByteArrayOutputStream object